# ADX: unable to ingest data via a control command using .NET sdk

Tags: c#, .net, azure-data-explorer

I defined a super-simple talbe:

```
.create table dummy (textfield: string)
```

I can properly execute an inline ingest command from **Query** panel:

```
.ingest inline into table dummy <| 'from query panel'
```

But I can't using **.NET** sdk:

```cs
using Kusto.Data;
using Kusto.Data.Common;
using Kusto.Data.Net.Client;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connection = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder("https://ingest-mycluster.westeurope.kusto.windows.net", "tracking")
                 .WithAadApplicationKeyAuthentication(
                     "MY_APPREG_ID",
                     "MY_APPREG_SECRET",
                     "MY_APPREG_TENANT");

        var client = KustoClientFactory.CreateCslAdminProvider(connection);

        client.ExecuteControlCommand(".ingest inline into table dummy <| 'from dot net'");

        //var cmd = CslCommandGenerator.GenerateTableIngestPushCommand("dummy", true, "textfield\ndotnettest");
        //client.ExecuteControlCommand(cmd);

        Console.WriteLine("completed");
    }
}
```

I've also tried with `CslCommandGenerator` bust still always getting same exeception:

```
Kusto.Data.Exceptions.SyntaxException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Syntax error: {
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest_SyntaxError",
        "message": "Request is invalid and cannot be executed.",
        "@type": "Kusto.Data.Exceptions.SyntaxException",
        "@message": "Syntax error: . Query: '.ingest inline into table dummy <| 'from dot net''",
        "@context": {
            "timestamp": "2021-04-19T07:45:11.8614191Z",
            "serviceAlias": "INGEST-ADXTESTCLUTER1",
            "machineName": "KDataMana000000",
            "processName": "Kusto.WinSvc.DM.Svc",
            "processId": 1596,
            "threadId": 3724,
            "appDomainName": "Kusto.WinSvc.DM.Svc.exe",
            "clientRequestId": "KD2RunCommand;a9e75e85-8ca7-43a0-b746-befcb92290a5",
            "activityId": "5c3bfc38-c2dd-4985-80d0-ed29adea9158",
            "subActivityId": "35a72a2f-129b-4691-8d06-4a1c6cf0384f",
            "activityType": "P.WCF.Service.ExecuteControlCommandInternal..IAdminClientServiceCommunicationContract",
            "parentActivityId": "ebe7b77f-ddc4-4bb6-ae71-72e9e50c7523",
            "activityStack": "(Activity stack: CRID=KD2RunCommand;a9e75e85-8ca7-43a0-b746-befcb92290a5 ARID=5c3bfc38-c2dd-4985-80d0-ed29adea9158 > DN.Admin.Client.ExecuteControlCommand/ebe7b77f-ddc4-4bb6-ae71-72e9e50c7523 > P.WCF.Service.ExecuteControlCommandInternal..IAdminClientServiceCommunicationContract/35a72a2f-129b-4691-8d06-4a1c6cf0384f)"
        },
        "@permanent": true
    }
}. Query: '.ingest inline into table dummy <| 'from dot net''
  Source=Kusto.Data
  StackTrace:
   at Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Http.KustoHttpClient.<ThrowKustoExceptionFromResponseMessageAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Kusto.Data.Net.Client.RestClient2.<MakeHttpRequestAsyncImpl>d__47.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Utils.MonitoredActivity.<InvokeAsync>d__12`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Utils.MonitoredActivity.<InvokeAsync>d__12`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Kusto.Data.Net.Client.RestClient2.<MakeHttpRequestAsync>d__45.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Kusto.Data.Net.Client.RestClient2.<ExecuteControlCommandAsync>d__40.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Utils.ExtendedTask.ResultEx[TResult](Task`1 task)
   at Kusto.Data.Net.Client.RestClient2.ExecuteControlCommand(String databaseName, String command, String addr, ClientRequestProperties properties)
   at Kusto.Data.Net.Client.RestClient2.ExecuteControlCommand(String command, ClientRequestProperties properties)
   at Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\coder\source\repos\AdxInjectTest\Program.cs:line 18

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    Program.Main(string[]) in Program.cs
```

It reports a syntax error, but the command query is valid.

What am I missing?

Regards, Giacomo S. S.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using the ingestion URI, and it's wrong.

The correct is: `https://mycluster.westeurope.kusto.windows.net`

Comment: The same thing happens when issuing any other control command, such as create table. I spent a whole day trying to understand until I came across your answer.